# Multilevel annotation/aggregation using django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have been trying to implement pretty much the same thing as in [query-for-total-score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893663/query-for-total-score)

Does Django support multilevel aggregation? I can get the max score for each user each challenge, but I don't know how to drill down my results to fit in.

```
s = Submission.objects.values('challenge','user').annotate(Max('score'),Max('total_score'))
```

This gives me list of dict with user, challenge, total_score and score

What I want is sum of scores for each user. When I use aggregate on this I am getting the sum of all scores

`s.aggregate(Sum('total_score__max'),Sum(score__max))`

Postgres sql query looks something like this

```
select "user_id", SUM("score__max") as "score", SUM("total_score__max") as "total_score", COUNT("challenge_id") as "count" from 
(SELECT "submission"."user_id", "submission"."challenge_id", MAX("submission"."score")
AS "score__max", MAX("submission"."total_score") AS "total_score__max" FROM "submission" 
GROUP BY "submission"."user_id", "submission"."challenge_id")t GROUP BY "user_id" ORDER BY "user_id";
```

Comment: Postgresql or mysql?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: Your core query would be like this right? `SELECT 'challenge','user',Max('score'), Max('total_score'), FROM submission GROUP BY Max('score'), Max('total_score'), user, challenge`

Comment: Yup that's right

Comment: Hey! I forgot what I wanted to text here for you, anyways now what exactly you need?

Comment: I want that sql query into django ORM statement. Is it possible ? If not how to do it efficiently. If I use a aggregate on above statement it gives me total score of all questions and user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166010/discussion-between-bhavani-ravi-and-anup-yadav).